# xpaths are different for same elements

Tags: xpath, web

I am working on test automation of a website that checks the content of Google Map Pin (typically address of the location).  The website is deployed on multiple servers for the purpose of load-balancing; therefore, I have to test on all the servers.

I find that the xpath to access the Map Pin is different on two sets of servers.  On one set of servers, it is:

```
.//*[@id='map']/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div
```

and on the other set, it is

```
.//*[@id="map"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div
```

I am puzzled as to why the xpaths would have different values.  Does it mean that the underlying code implementation is different?  The code on the two sets of servers was deployed two weeks apart. BTW, I am using the same version of Chrome driver and am running the tests on the same virtual machine.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not surprising that you get different results when you use different XPaths. The predicates selecting elements at different positions will select different things. It would be helpful to post some example HTML that these XPaths are being executed against. Are you trying to figure out how/why the HTML is different, and therefore different XPath statements are generated? How are you obtaining those XPath statements?

Comment: Hi Mads, may be I was not clear in my question...the test is trying to access the same element on two different servers. The xpath being used in both cases was originally  gathered by "inspecting" the element in Google Chrome browser.  When the element was not found on one of the servers, I "inspect"ed it and came to know about the difference in xpaths.

Comment: Well, the first place that the XPaths diverge is `.//*[@id='map']/div/div/div[1]`. The first one selects the 4th div and the second one selects the 3rd. Take a look at that div's content and see what is different. Again, it's hard to diagnose what is different between two HTML documents that you have not posted for us to inspect.

Comment: Paths like this are not going to be very stable. See if you can identify a more stable path that relies on id attribute values.

Comment: I just identified a stable xpath - //div[@class='gomapMarker'] - that I can use from now on. But using the generic xpath has helped me identify a potential implementaion / deployment issues; and am trying to see what caused this difference.